# Raw sound files editors, 8bit

Tags: audio, 8-bit, raw-file, soundfile

I was wondering if anyone knows how to open and edit a raw sound file (raw unsigned 8-bit). 
I am making my own game and trying to create original 8-bit music.
I could not open SoX, and all other editors I have cannot play these frequencies correctly.
I appreciate all help.

Comment: Audacity is rather nice for many audio tasks dunno if it allows file editing ... raw audio is simply points along the curve so if you write some code to synthesize that curve you can do your edits programmatically ... this would depend on what kind of changes you need to make edits for

Comment: thank you very much @ScottStensland, I did use Audacity eventually! Some sounds were getting distorted when imported and some were distorted after exporting them from Audacity, which I found very weird. But I managed.

Comment: as an aside sonicvisualiser.org is the best tool to show a spectrogram ... Layer -> melodic spectrogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using beep box. you can recover work from the past 30 days. or, you can try import a .mid file. you can have 4 base notes, and set the instrements to 8-bit sounds, crunches and waves. hope it works for you! --> beepbox.org or search it up if this link doesnt work
This kind of sounds like a sponser for some reason